# Unit Testable convention for Service "Helper Classes" in DDD pattern

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, mockito, domain-driven-design

I'm fairly new to Java and joining a project that leverages the DDD pattern (supposedly). I come from a strong python background and am fairly anal about unit test driven design. That said, one of the challenges of moving to Java is the testability of Service layers.

Our REST-like project stack is laid out as follows:

- `ServiceHandlers` which handles request/response, etc and calls specific implementations of `IService` (eg. `DocumentService`)
- `DocumentService` - handles auditing, permission checking, etc with methods such as `makeOwner(session, user, doc)`

Currently, something like `DocumentService` has repository dependencies injected via guice. In a public method like `DocumentService.makeOwner`, we want to ensure the session user is an admin as well as check if the target user is already an owner (leveraging the injected repositories). This results in some dupe code - one for both users involved to resolve the user and ensure membership, permissions, etc etc. To eliminate this redundant code, I want make a sort of super simple`isOwner(user, doc)` call that I can concisely mock out for various test scenarios (such as throwing the exception when the user can't be resolved, etc). Here is where my googling fails me.

If I put this in the same class as `DocumentService`, I can't mock it while testing `makeOwner` in the same class (due to Mockito limitations) even though it somewhat feels like it should go here (option1).

If I put it in a lower class like `DocumentHelpers`, it feels slightly funny but I can easily mock it out. Also, DocumentHelpers needs the injected repository as well, which is fine with guice. (option 2)

I should add that there are numerous spots of this nature in our infant code base that are untestable currently because methods are non-statically calling helper-like methods in the same *Service class not used by the upper ServiceHandler class. However, at this stage, I can't tell if this is poor design or just fine.

So I ask more experienced Java developers:

1. Does introducing "Service Helpers" seem like a valid solution?
2. Is this counter to DDD principals?
3. If not, is there are more DDD-friendly naming convention for this aside from "Helpers"?

3 bits to add:

- My googling has mostly come up with debates over "helpers" as static utility methods for stateless operations like date formatting, which doesn't fit my issue.
- I don't want to use PowerMock since it breaks code coverage and is pretty ugly to use.
- In python I'd probably call the "Service Helper" layer described above as internal_api, but that seems to have a different meaning in Java, especially since I need the classes to be public to unit test them.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Does it matter that the document owner remains an admin at all times or is it just an initial prerequisite?

Comment: It's a somewhat arbitrary case, but re-reading it I actually meant that we need to check the target user is already an owner, not admin. But in general, only admins can promote/demote doc owners in this example. Good catch, I'll update.

Comment: I think the only problem here is that the responsibility of `DocumentService` is too large. Your domain is about documents, but then having a `DocumentService` is like a code smell. You may have a `DocumentHandlingService` which is responsible for handing over  ownership and you may also have a `DocumentPermissionService` and a `DocumentAuditingService`. You may want to strip `Document` from those service names.

Answer (score 0):

That the user who initiates the action must be an admin looks like an application-level access control concern. DDD doesn't have much of an opinion about how you should do that. For testability and separation of concerns purposes, it might be a better idea to have some kind of separate non-static class than a method in the same service or a static helper though.

Checking that the future owner is already an owner (if I understand correctly) might be a different animal. It could be an invariant in your domain. If so, the preferred way is to rely on an Aggregate to enforce that rule. However, it's not clear from your description whether `Document` is an aggregate and if it or another aggregate contains the data needed to tell if a user is owner.

Alternatively, you could verify the rule at the Application layer level but it means that your domain model could go inconsistent if the state change is triggered by something else than that Application layer.

Answer (score 0):

As I learn more about DDD, my question doesn't seem to be all that DDD related and more just about general hierarchy of the code structure and interactions of the layers. We ended up going with a separate DocumentServiceHelpers class that could be mocked out. This contains methods like isOwner that we can mock to return true or false as needed to test our DocumentService handling more easily. Thanks to everyone for playing along.